# python print in format way unknown list length

Tags: python, list, printing, format

If I have a 6 length list like this:

`l = ["AA","BB","CC","DD"]`

I can print it with:

`print "%-2s %-2s %-2s %-2s" % tuple(l)`

The output will be:

`AA BB CC DD`

But what if the list l could be in any length? Is there a way to print the list in the same format with unknown number of elements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generate separate snippets and join them:

```
print ' '.join(['%-2s' % (i,) for i in l])
```

Or you can use string multiplication:

```
print ('%-2s ' * len(l))[:-1] % tuple(l)
```

The `[:-1]` removes the extraneous space at the end; you could use `.rstrip()` as well.

Demo:

```
>>> print ' '.join(['%-2s' % (i,) for i in l])
AA BB CC DD
>>> print ' '.join(['%-2s' % (i,) for i in (l + l)])
AA BB CC DD AA BB CC DD
>>> print ('%-2s ' * len(l))[:-1] % tuple(l)
AA BB CC DD
>>> print ('%-2s ' * len(l))[:-1] % tuple(l + l)
AA BB CC DD AA BB CC DD
```

Timing stats:

```
>>> def joined_snippets(l):
...     ' '.join(['%-2s' % (i,) for i in l])
... 
>>> def joined_template(l):
...     ' '.join(['%-2s' for i in l])%tuple(l)
... 
>>> def multiplied_template(l):
...     ('%-2s ' * len(l))[:-1] % tuple(l)
... 
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> l = ["AA","BB","CC","DD"]
>>> timeit('f(l)', 'from __main__ import l, joined_snippets as f')
1.3180170059204102
>>> timeit('f(l)', 'from __main__ import l, joined_template as f')
1.080280065536499
>>> timeit('f(l)', 'from __main__ import l, multiplied_template as f')
0.7333378791809082
>>> l *= 10
>>> timeit('f(l)', 'from __main__ import l, joined_snippets as f')
10.041708946228027
>>> timeit('f(l)', 'from __main__ import l, joined_template as f')
5.52706503868103
>>> timeit('f(l)', 'from __main__ import l, multiplied_template as f')
2.8013129234313965
```

The multiplied template option leaves the other options in the dust.

Comment: Took me a moment to realise why yours was faster than mine. It's one of those cases where the list comprehension smokes a generator expression

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to achieve that without join? something like `print "%-2s ... %-2s" % tuple(l)`. I did it with join before but I wondered if there is some built-in support for that. Thanks again

Comment: @user1692261, you can use `'%-2s '*len(l)%tuple(l)`, but that leaves an extra space on the end. It may not matter for you though

Comment: @user1692261: there, now you have multiple options and timing info on what is the faster approach.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
' '.join(['%-2s' for i in l])%tuple(l)
```

I found this to be more than twice as fast as using a generator expression

```
' '.join('%-2s' for i in l)%tuple(l)
```

This is faster still

```
'%-2s '*len(l)%tuple(l) # leaves an extra trailing space though
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tests = [
    ["AA"],
    ["AA", "BB"],
    ["AA", "BBB", "CCC"]
]

for test in tests:
    format_str = "%-2s " * len(test)
    print format_str

--output:--
%-2s 
%-2s %-2s 
%-2s %-2s %-2s
```

Comment: Your output has a trailing space, which may not be what the OP wants or is expecting.

Comment: Too bad python doesn't have an rstrip() function. Or string slicing. :(

Comment: Har-dy-har. Or were you serious about that? http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip

Comment: lol.  I see now that you posted the same thing 4 minutes ahead of me.  Or did you add that to your post after I posted?? SO is too confusing.

Comment: I did edit things in in the grace period, yes. I tend to do that a lot; add more info and detail as I go along.

Comment: Same here, no problem.  I only posted because I didn't see any answers  that used string multiplication.